# Различие basic_istream и istream

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

В чем разница между basic_istream и istream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`basic_istream` это шаблон:

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>>
class basic_istream;
```

`istream` и `wistream` - это псевдонимы (*) этого шаблона, для случаев когда `charT` это `char` и `wchar_t` соответственно.

```
using istream = basic_istream<char>;
using wistream = basic_istream<wchar_t>;
```

*) Тут можно было бы использовать термин "специализация" или "инстанциация", однако применительно к `using` и `typedef`, эти термины вызывают много споров (в частности мы не знаем реализован ли `basic_istream<char>` как явная специализация или нет).

Answer (score 7):

Между ними нет отличий, т.к. `istream` это ничто иное как `basic_istream<char>`.

Comment: Ну, я бы всё же сказал, что одно — частный случай второго.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я помню, там нет никакой отдельной специализации, поэтому говорить о частном случае, как мне кажется, неуместно. Это простая инстанциация.

Comment: Ну да. Я к тому, что `istream` — это `basic_stream<char>`, то есть это конкретная инстанциация шаблона. А `basic_istream` — просто сам шаблон. Частный случай не в смысле наследования.